# $e^{\large\frac{-t}{5}}(1-\frac{t}{5})=0$ solve for t

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm given the following equation an i have to solve for $"t"$ This is actually the derivative of a function, set equal to zero:
$$f'(t) = e^\frac{-t}{5}(1-\frac{t}{5})=0$$

I will admit im just stuck and im looking for how to solve this efficiently.

steps $1,\;2$ - rewrote the equation and distributed:
$$\frac{1}{e^\frac{t}{5}}(1-\frac{t}{5}) \iff \frac{1-\frac{t}{5}}{e^\frac{t}{5}} $$

steps $3, \;4$ - common denominator of 5,  multiply by reciprocal of denominator:

$$ \frac{\frac{5-t}{5}}{e^\frac{t}{5}}\iff\frac{\frac{5-t}{5}}*\frac{1}{e^\frac{t}{5}}  = \frac{5-t}{5e^\frac{t}{5}}  $$

step 5, set  this is where I,m stuck:

$$f'(t) = \frac{5-t}{5e^\frac{t}{5}}=0$$

How do i go from here? And am I even doing this correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Miguel

Comment: Hint: $e^{-t/5}$ is never $0$.

Comment: thanks tom that hint made alot of sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Given either presentation of your derivative: $$e^{-t/5}(1-\frac{t}{5})=0\tag{1}$$
$$\iff \frac{5-t}{5e^{t/5}}=0\tag{2}$$

Note that neither the factor $\,e^{-t/5}\,$ in $(1)$, nor the denominator $\,e^{t/5}\,$ of $(2)$ will ever evaluate to zero: i.e. $e^{-t/5} = \dfrac 1{e^{t/5}}\neq 0,\;$ whatever the value of $t$.

With this in mind, for simplicity, we'll look at equation $(2)$: your derivative will equal zero when and only when the numerator equals zero.

I.e., solve for $t$ given: $\quad 5 - t = 0$.

Comment: thanks for pulling me out of the gutter again amWhy. I truly apreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, Miguel!

Comment: @amWhy: I am going to go bed. Unfortunately, I couldn't be here today for hours. May be  next days. :-)

Answer (score 2):

$e^{\dfrac{-t}{5}}\neq0$. (Cause: $\frac{1}{e^\frac{t}{5}}$ is a real number)

Therefore, the other term has to be zero.

Now you can solve it !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an even simpler approach. Your equation is a product of terms, so one of them (or both) must equal $0$ in order for the product to equal $0$.

From the first term one gets $e^{-\frac{t}{5}} = 0$ which is asymptotically true as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

From the second term one gets $1 - \frac{t}{5} = 0$ which has the obvious solution $t=5$.